# Is there a way to define a list data structure with specific element types in Python 3.9 type hinting?

Tags: python, list, type-hinting, python-3.9

For example, I want to define data structure `X`, where `X` is a `list` with three elements. The first element and third are strings and the second element is an integer. So something like this:

```
X = List[str, int, str]
```

Is there a proper way to define something like this?

Comment: Lists are designed to be dynamic. They can be sorted, items can be popped of and inserted at any position. So, your requirement makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists are normally meant for collections of data of unknown length. A [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple) suits better to your use case:

```
from typing import Tuple

MyType = Tuple[str, int, str]
my_tuple: MyType = ("foo", 42, "bar")
```

Update: As @sj95126 mentioned in their comment, you don't have to import `typing.Tuple` starting with Python >= 3.9:

```
MyType = tuple[str, int, str]
```

Comment: In Python 3.9, it's now supported to use, e.g. ```tuple[str, int, str]``` without importing ```typing```.

Comment: @Selcuk I need to be able to change individual values within the data structure frequently (while still sticking to the structure), which is why I thought it'd be better to use a list. Should I still switch to a tuple?

Comment: @Ice `tuple`s are immutable, so you can't really _change_ them. You can mutate a `list` but you can't guarantee the number of elements in it. It might be a better idea to create a custom class (a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) perhaps).

Comment: @Selcuk Ok, thanks for the help!